# Is or Are? --> Every year, about 800,000 tonnes of food waste are generated

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, quantifiers

I need some help with the following sentence:

> Every year, about 800,000 tonnes of food waste **are** generated.

Should it be "are" or "is"? (as bolded above)

Comment: i really like to know what the actual answer is, but i think `is` would be used if someone or something is doing it, and `are` to be used when we are talking about groups of thing doing so. my bet is on the `are`.

Comment: Every year about 10**35 electrons are burned up arguing this issue.

Comment: @HotLicks Every year, about 90 tonnes of electrons are burned up arguing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

My sense of grammar would have

> about 800,000 tonnes of food

a complex descriptor of *waste*.

I can also sense

> about 800,000

and

> of food waste

as modifiers of *tonnes.*

This being so, I think the only reasonable answer  would have to come by knowing the context of the sentence. That is, the general subject of the paragraph from which the sentence in question has been lifted.

Without context, for me the scales tilt toward "waste is generated".

Answer (score 1):

The author structured this sentence in the [passive voice](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/539/03/), and thus omits **who** is generating the 800,000 tonnes of food waste. This use of the passive voice likely contributes to the confusion over identification of the parts of speech and, in turn, subject-verb agreement.

I'm a fan of [sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_diagram) [diagramming](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/10/01/diagram-sentence-grammar_n_5908462.html) but, even without it, we can see that "tonnes" is the subject of the sentence (whereas [it would be the object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice) if the sentence were rewritten in the active voice, because it is the noun that is acted upon).

Stripped to its subject and verb, the sentence is "Tonnes **are** generated." This is because the subject, "tonnes" is plural. Everything else in the sentence is a modifier. The verb here cannot be said to modify "food waste" because that noun is preceded by the preposition "[of](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of)" and comprises a prepositional phrase that functions as an adjective, modifying the subject, to signify **what** the tonnes are.

One also can approach the analysis interrogatively (question in italics and answer, in the form of a sentence modifier, in bold):

- Tonnes are generated. (root sentence)
- *Tonnes of what are generated?*
- Tonnes **of food waste** are generated.
- *How many tonnes of food waste are generated?*
- **About 800,000** tonnes of food waste are generated.
- *How often are about 800,000 tonnes of food waste generated?*
- **Every year**, about 800,000 tonnes of food waste are generated.

Of course, the difficulty with subject-verb agreement here disappears if the sentence is rewritten in the active voice. With "humans" as the subject and "tonnes" becoming the object, for example, we can see immediately that the verb "are generated" becomes "generate":

- Every year, humans generate about 800,000 tonnes of food waste.

One final observation: It's worth noting that the sentence in the active voice offers more information to the reader -- and also places the additional burden on the author -- by identifying **who** is generating the food waste. Is this 800,000 tonnes being generated by *all* humans? By one nation (e.g. could we replace "humans" with a more specific noun, such as "Americans")? By one industry (replace "humans" with "restaurants")? Is it possible that the author did not know, or did not wish to call out with greater specificity, those responsible for generating the quantity of food waste at issue? The omission of such potentially important information is one of the dangers of the passive voice -- more dangerous than an entertaining question about number!

Comment: "year" and "waste" are also nouns (and arguably "food" as well). A noun inside a prepositional phrase is still a noun.

Comment: Yes, out of context, they are still nouns, but they are not nouns insofar as their roles in the sentence as written. When a noun is contained in a prepositional phrase that serves as an adjective, the entire phrase operates as an adjective.

Comment: Well, the traditional terminology is that the noun is the "object" of the preposition. "Operates as an adjective" seems to be an OK description of how prepositional phrases work in some contexts, although it's quite vague and cound be considered misleading--there are differences as well as similarities. But I know many people use this kind of description. In contrast, I don't think I've encountered anyone before who said that nouns in prepositional phrases were not nouns in the context of the surrounding sentence, so I think that part of your answer is likely to cause some confusion.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with your assertion that "waste" in the original sentence is a noun that is the object of the preposition. But the fact that it is contained in a prepositional phrase that modifies the subject makes that phrase an adjective in the sentence.

Comment: One piece of evidence that nouns in prepositional phrases still count as nouns even at the sentence level is anaphora. We can refer back to a noun in a prepositional phrase using a pronoun. Because of phenomena like this, I don't think it is helpful to say that nouns in prepositional phrases don't count as nouns or don't function as nouns. After all, a word may have a different function than the phrase it is contained in.

Comment: Example: [The flatness *of* **the country** makes **it** (=the country) very uninteresting](https://books.google.com/books?id=4NsEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA130&dq=%22of+the+country+makes+it%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_4PXer5XZAhWg8oMKHeRdCbsQ6AEIODAD#v=onepage&q=%22of%20the%20country%20makes%20it%22&f=false)

Comment: [The smallness *of* **the book** makes **it** (=the book) fit for the pocket](https://books.google.com/books?id=Z8UDAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA2&dq=%22of+the+book+makes+it%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYwZWVsJXZAhUj64MKHQMFA24Q6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=%22of%20the%20book%20makes%20it%22&f=false)

Comment: Your point is well taken and appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I would go for the singular form of the verb in this case, since 'food' is a non-count noun.

Comment: *Food* has nothing to do with anything here. The choice is between *tonnes* and *waste*. While *food* is not even a noun here.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: "food" is arguably an attributive noun in this context. However, distinguishing between atttributive nouns and adjectives can be difficult.

Comment: Correct, I should have said that waste was a non-count noun.